# Shifting the entire Matrix to the left side

Tags: math-mode

When I use \begin{pmatrix}.. \end{pmatrix} in beamer the matrix is centered in the middle of the slide, but I want it to be shifted to the top left corner, is there a way to do that?

Comment: pmatrix does not position itself in any way, if it is centered you must have placed it in an environment that centres its content such as `\[ \]`.

Comment: Please show MWE, which will show your problem. Do you like to have all equation left aligned or just this matrix?

Comment: yes the problem was \[ \], I replaced it with $$ and it worked.